# Getting the tangent line from tangent space

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider the system of equations $x^2+2y^2+3z^2=3$ and $x^2-y^2+z^2=5$. The tangent plane at the point $(1,1,1)^t$ is given by the kernel of the derivative of the system. That is, $\ker \left(\begin{matrix}
2x&4y&6z\\ 2x&-2y&2z
\end{matrix} \right)_{(1,1,1)^T}=\ker\left(\begin{matrix}
2&4&6\\ 2&-2&2
\end{matrix} \right),$
which is the set of all $(x,y,z)$ such that $6y=-4z$. Assuming I did not make a mistake...

Thus we have a description of tangent space to the intersection at the point $(1,1,1)^t$. Suppose now I want to find the equation of the line that passes through our point. This seems as if it should be easy...

I am also asking if my reasoning above is correct.

Comment: There are infinite number of lines that lies on tangent plane and goes through your point. Is there any restriction to specify which line you need?

Comment: I figure this is looking for the tangent line to the intersection of the two surfaces, which is locally unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sign of a problem is that $\{(x,y,z):6y=-4z\}$ is two-dimensional, while you're looking for a tangent *line*. The most systematic way to find the kernel of your derivative is row reduction, which ought to come out to
$$A=\left(\begin{matrix} 1&0&\frac{5}{3}\\0&1&\frac{2}{3}\end{matrix}\right)$$
Do you know how to find the kernel at this point? If not, that's a necessary skill for this material on which you should work separately.

Let's say you do, and it turns out to be 1-dimensional as we wanted, $\ker A=tv$ for some
fixed $v\in\Bbb{R}^3$ and $t$ varying over $\Bbb{R}$. Then your tangent line is simply this 1-dimensional linear space shifted to the point of interest: $(1,1,1)^t+tv$.